# replicate curl command python 3 urllib request API

Tags: python-3.x, curl, httprequest

This problem is kind of driving me crazy.
I'm doing a very simple  python 3 script to manage an API in a public website.
I am able to do it with curl, but not in pyhton.
Can't use either requests library or curl in my real environment, just for tests

This is working:

```
curl -d "credential_0=XXXX&credential_1=XXXXXX" -c cookiefile.txt https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/LOGIN

curl -d 'json={"devices" : ["00:1A:1E:29:73:B2","00:1A:1E:29:73:B2"]}' -b cookiefile.txt -v https://XXXXXXXXX/api-path --trace-ascii /dev/stdout
```

and we can see this in the curl debug:

Send header, 298 bytes (0x12a)

0000: POST /api-path HTTP/1.1

0034: Host: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

0056: User-Agent: curl/7.47.0

006f: Accept: */*

007c: Cookie: csrf_token=751b6bd9-0290-496b-820e-XXXXXXXX; session
00bc: =XXXXXX-6d29-4cf9-8907-XXXXXXXXXXXX

00e3: Content-Length: 60

00f7: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

0128: 
=> Send data, 60 bytes (0x3c)

0000: json={"devices" : ["00:1A:1E:29:73:B2","00:1A:1E:29:73:B2"]}
== Info: upload completely sent off: 60 out of 60 bytes

This is the python code to replicate the second request, which is the problematic one

```
string_query={"devices" : [ "34:FC:B9:CE:14:7E","00:1A:1E:29:73:B2" ]}
jsonbody_url=urllib.parse.urlencode(string_query)
jsonbody_url=jsonbody_url.encode("utf-8")

req=urllib.request.Request(url,data=jsonbody_url,headers={"Cookie" : 
cookie,"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded","User-
Agent":"curl/7.47.0","charset":"UTF-8","Content-
length":len(jsonbody_url),
"Connection": "Keep-Alive"},method='POST')
```

And the server is completely ignoring the Json content.
Everything else is working, login and other url parameters from the same API

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import requests

string_query={"devices" : [ "34:FC:B9:CE:14:7E","00:1A:1E:29:73:B2" ]}
headers={
  "Cookie" : cookie,
  "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  "User-Agent":"curl/7.47.0",
  "charset":"UTF-8",
  "Connection": "Keep-Alive"
}
response = requests.post(url,data=string_query,headers=headers)
print(response.content)
```

Comment: Hello, already have tried Request module just to get a response from the server (As I said I can't use it the working environemnt) but no luck. Server is ignoring the json imput. I'm starting to think the server API has a problem. Thanks

Comment: You can use urllib only?

Comment: If you could provide the docs or the endpoint of the API it might have another solution.

Comment: Yes, only urllib. The API documentation is not very helpful I guess. I opened a case to support and their last reponse is : "You need to use form data, not JSON payload." I figure out that the solution might be copying the exact curl request that is actually working, that's why I posted the cURL debug. Regards

Comment: Yes I did have I thought aout that as your cURL debug was showing but I neglected it over the -d option in the cURL command you provided. I guess you need to make a session to access the resource maybe.

Comment: You think? It's strange that I can access resources by some URL filters in the same API but the server is not fetching the JSON data. Regards